# Using htaccess, is it safe to redirect user to SSL domain and login from there?

Tags: .htaccess, security, mod-rewrite, ssl, authentication

I'm working on a web builder system, and I want allow people to add forum to their site. Therefor, each website should have his own logging form, but it is of course not possible. So I decided that all the website will be in the DB, and all the domain will be redirecting to specific PHP page that will show the code of the website they want to see.

I used wildcard to be able to let people enter each website from a subdomain and using HTACCESS they will see the PHP page. The logging form is in the same host and domain (the main domain) of the PHP page that shows the websites and this is the only domain that has SSL. I can't buy a wildcard SSL because it won't help me because I want allow people to add their own domain. So I thought to myself, and is it safe to log in like that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule login https://www.example.com/login.php [NC,QSA]
```

and is there a way to show that the login is secure?

Comment: Are you redirecting from your site to another users domain?

Comment: @PanamaJack no. When user enters to `http://myweb.example.com/login`, the system resiracts to `https://www.example.com/login.php` (without the user to know that he war redirected).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> I can't buy a wildcard SSL because it won't help me because I want
>   allow people to add their own domain.

Why won't it help you? You can buy a wildcard cert and use it on your subdomains so that it will also have `https` then you won't have to worry about it. That is what `NameBased VirtualHosts` can be used for.

Example you can buy a wildcard for you site. `*.yoursite.com` Now you can setup your system to use name-based setup for all subdomains.

Here you see an example of two subdomains using the same SSL Cert.

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.yoursite.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.yoursite.com.key

        ServerName      "one.yoursite.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/one"

        CustomLog       "/var/log/httpd/one-access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/var/log/httpd/one-error.log"

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride none

                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 192.168.1.1:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP

        SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/star.yoursite.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile   /etc/ssl/star.yoursite.com.key

        ServerName      "two.yoursite.com"
        DocumentRoot    "/var/www/html/two"

        CustomLog       "/var/log/httpd/two-access.log" combined
        ErrorLog        "/var/log/httpd/two-error.log"

        <Directory /var/www/html>
                AllowOverride none

                Order Allow,Deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Please see this **[apache doc](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHosts)** for information on **`Name-Based VirtualHosts and SSL.`**
This method is used by many sites who want to provide a subdomain to every user and only have one wildcard cert.

Then the user can go to `https://user1.yoursite.com/login` and you shouldn't need to redirect just to use SSL.

**SIDE NOTE ADDED:**

Also why do you need to **HIDE** the fact that you are using SSL? You are a service provider of some sort correct? It's not uncommon to redirect to the main site for authentication and then redirect back to the previous URL which is the users subdomain site. Look at Youtube which is owned by Google. When I click `login` on Youtube, I am redirected to Google's main login page, once authenticated it redirects me back to YouTube. Their is no point to go through what you are doing to obscure the process. People feel safe when they know the connection is secure. I for one hesitate to use a site that doesn't have `https` on their login/signup page in 2014. So what's the problem? Just redirect, login and go back.

Comment: I can't use a wildcard because user can add his own domain, so what about them? They won't have SSL? This is not secure.

Comment: I'm confused by what you mean the user will add `his own domain`. You just told me that it was going to be http://myweb.example.com. How is that their own domain? Give me an example of their domain name.

Comment: I writed that this is a web builder system. myweb.example.com it is just example. It can be vlad.example.com and if you own domain you can make that your domain will show the website you'll build in my system.

Comment: Exactly, that is what a wildcard cert is for. `example.com` is **YOUR** main domain that **YOU** host. `vlad.example.com` is a **subdomain** of `example.com`. `tom.example.com` or `john.example.com` or `mattsmith.example.com` are all subdomains and can use the same wildcard SSL, so you can use name-based virtual hosts and use **one** wildcard ssl as I posted.

Comment: But again, what about the people who have their own domain? Yes, wildcard can help me with the subdomains, but if I own the domain www.coolsite.com and I want him to show my website that I've build using my system, the wildcard won't help.

Comment: Well if you are just showing off your site that you built why do you need SSL? I thought you only required it for authentication purposes. Why do you need it for just showing or display what you've done? Maybe I don't understand your builder system.

Comment: Because the websites may have forum, and the forum have his own member system.

Comment: Then maybe they need to worry about their own SSL cert for their own website. See side note comment above.

Comment: I don't want hide the SSL from users, I won't want that users of the websites (not the owners) know that the website build in my system (Forum is only for premium, and if they payed this is won't be fair to show everyone that they build in my system.)
Do you suggest to redirect users to my main domain to login and then redirect them to the website?

Comment: Yes. That should probably be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

> hen user enters to `http://myweb.example.com/login`, the system resiracts to `https://www.example.com/login.php` (without the user to know that he war redirected)

There's a few things here. You can't redirect to the SSL resource without the user knowing about the redirect. In order to even *take advantage* of SSL encryption, the browser must initiate a handshake with the server to negotiate the encryption. If the browser doesn't know that it needs to use SSL (via the "https://" scheme), then the browser won't encrypt the content. If the browser knows about the redirect, it's going to display the new URL, e.g. `https://www.exmaple.com/login.php`. If the browser doesn't know that it needs to encrypt the connection, what's the point of using SSL behind the scenes? The communication over the internet between the browser and the webserver is unencrypted.

Something you *can* do, is redirect `http://myweb.example.com/login` to `https://myweb.example.com/login` then **reverse proxy** that to `https://www.example.com/login.php`. But since you don't want to buy a cert for `myweb.example.com`, you're simply not going to have encryption at all.

As for the reverse proxy, you'll need to have mod_proxy loaded and use the `P` flag in your rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule login https://www.example.com/login.php [NC,QSA,P]
```

There may also be some issues with proxying to https, so you can try to reverse proxy to `http://www.example.com/login.php` if you get an error.

Comment: When I'm saying `without the browser know` I mean that I'll redirect is using htaccess but the URL line won't change. And I have no https t the subdomains.

Comment: @VladGincher I know what you mean, and like I said, if the URL line doesn't change, the connection between the browser and the server isn't encrypted. So not sure why you're even using HTTPS at this point.

Comment: Because it is not safe login without it, right? And if I'll add an `iframe` with HTTPS, will it be secured?

Comment: @VladGincher doesn't matter. **If the URL on the browser doesn't change to HTTPS there will BE NO ENCRYPTION**. Even if you reverse proxy to an HTTPS url, the actual connection between the browser and the server is left completely unencrypted. If you add an iframe to log in, then yes, the iframe's source will be HTTPS and thus the browser will initiate an encrypted connection.

Comment: @VladGincher bad idea. You don't want to hide that from your users. Look at my side note comment.

Comment: I mean that in `http://myweb.example.com/login` the only code will be is `<iframe src="https://www.example.com/login.php"></iframe>` and no HTACCESS. It won't work either?

Answer (score 0):

Redirecting user to a SSL login/registration interface is a good thing as it provides more security to user profile and data being exchanged between server – user. However, when we talk about the wildcard SSL certificate, it can be used on multiple sub domains of a domain which will be beneficial for your forum site. A wildcard SSL certificate is valid in following domain formation:

> - www.company.com
> - company.com
> - login-secure.company.com
> - payment.company.com
> - contact.company.com

So you can use it without any problem. Many companies such as Skype, UberConference uses such type of SSL protection. With increasing cyber threats and spam, it has become important to safeguard your website and user data with the usage of SSL protection, spam prevention services such as ScrapeSentry, Copyrights, DMCA certificates etc. So I would suggest you to go for SSL protection such as wildcard in your subdomain site.